Setting height of v-footer
I'm trying to reduce the height of the v-footer component and the documentation says I can use the height prop. However, no matter if I try height="100px" or height="50%", the footer stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

        <v-footer absolute class="bg-light-blue-lighten-3 d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center"  height="100px">
            <p class="font-weight-bold text-h6">sample text</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">sample text</p>
            <p>sample text</p>
            <p>sample text</p>
            <p><v-icon icon="mdi-map-marker"></v-icon>location<p>
        </v-footer>

image of the footer:


When you inspect the HTML generated from v-footer does it look like the content is overflowing? Also, try passing a number :height="100". Remove "absolute" attribute to see if that changes anything

@aleksKamb I tried that but it didnt seem to work. In the end I managed to reduce the height by adding the flex-grow-0 class.

What is your overflow-y value?
If you have a "scroll" or "hide" value the size will be ok.
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    v-footer {
                        background: red;
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 100px;
                        overflow-y: hidden;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
        <body>
        <v-footer absolute class="bg-light-blue-lighten-3 d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center"  height="100px">
            <p class="font-weight-bold text-h6">sample text</p>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">sample text</p>
            <p>sample text</p>
            <p>sample text</p>
            <p><v-icon icon="mdi-map-marker"></v-icon>location<p>
            </v-footer>
        </body>
    </html>

